# Download de imagens

Tags: php, javascript, html5, qrcode

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 <section class="margem-base-80 coluna  sombra-suave" id="recipiente-topo">

<h1 class="margem-topo-50 recipiente letra-branca">Gerar QRcode 
gratuitamente</h1>
<main class="em-linha" id="main-index">

<article class="recipiente" id="campo-qr">
  <form class="coluna" method="post">
    <label for="gerar-qr">Endereço web (URL)</label>
    <input type="text" name="code" id="code-input" 
placeholder="http://exemplo.com" required />
    <input type="hidden" name="gerar" value="s">
    <div>
    <button class="btn-azul margem-topo-50">Gerar QR code</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</article>

<?php

  if(isset($_POST['gerar'])) {

    require_once "interno/phpqrcode/qrlib.php";

    $valor = $_POST['code'];

    $code = $valor;

    QRcode::png($code, "Imagem_QRCODE_M.png", QR_ECLEVEL_M, 8);

    $qr= '<img id="tamanho-code" src="Imagem_QRCODE_M.png"/>';
  ?>  
<article class="recipiente" id="qr-campo">
  <?=$qr?>
</article>
  <?php
  } else { ?>
<article class="recipiente" id="qr-campo">
</article>
 <?php
  }
?>

</main>
</section>
```

Esta imagem de exemplo não está em um banco de dados e também não está em uma pasta entre os arquivos do site, está apenas sendo exibida no site através do meu código html por ser uma imagem qr code que o site gera recebendo os dados via post. Para algum usuário salvar esta imagem em seu computador ele tem que clicar com o botão direito do mouse e logo depois ir em salvar imagens. Como posso fazer para adicionar o meu button faça o download desta imagem assim que o cliente clicar nele?

Comment: Por favor refaça a sua pergunta de forma mais clara não estou conseguindo entender o que quer, coloque o código que tu tem, diga o que ele está fazendo e o que deveria fazer

Comment: na verdade eu coloquei o código, mas não está aparecendo.. é somente um img src e um button abaixo.. eu editei a pergunta para ser mais claro agora..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se entendi, mas se você quer um botão que baixe uma imagem é isso:

```
<a href="caminho_do_arquivo.txt" download="Nome do arquivo"><button>Download</button></a>
```

O atributo `download` faz com que o arquivo mencionado no `href` seja baixado com o nome determinado nele podendo conter espaços, porém o nome no `href` não pode conter espaços

Observação: para seu código html aprarecer você precisa colocar 4 espaços antes tipo, em vez de

código...

colocar:

```
código...
```

Esses 4 espaços é para o site entender que o que você vai digitar é um bloco de código e não um código, por isso está aparecendo literalmente um botão, porque você colocou um `<button>`

É isso?

Comment: Ela não tem um caminho, como coloquei na pergunta. Essa imagem é um qrcode que eu gero recebendo informações via post

Comment: tente arrumar sua pergunta mostrando seu código

Comment: Obrigado pela dica dos 4 espaços @GuilhermeCotamilam

Comment: Repito, meu problema é que não tenho um herf na imagem.. ela é gerada e exibida no site por dados que recebo via post

Comment: eu posso colocar um href com qualquer valor? e mesmo que a imagem se alterar com a geração de um novo qrcode vai baixar?

Comment: em html não, porém com js você pode atribuir uma variável ao `href`, é isso que pretende? coloque o seu código que gere o `qrcode`

Comment: editei a pergunta e coloquei o meu código inteiro. Tem como me ajudar? Se a solução for js eu não saberei fazer

Comment: Primeiro tente colocar o `src` do `<img>`, funciona? caso não, clique com o botão direito na imagem e clique em copiar endereço da imagem, tenta colocar esse endereço, se não funcionar coloque o endereço aqui nos comentários

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeCostamilam